# Cron script error on readness check

Tags: magento2, cron, setup-upgrade

```
> Check Cron Scripts Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail
> 
> Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
> 
> Found non-writable path(s): /var/www/html/pub/media/.htaccess
> /var/www/html/pub/media/customer/.htaccess
> /var/www/html/pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess
> /var/www/html/pub/media/import
> /var/www/html/pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
> 
> For additional assistance, see cron scripts help.
```

I tried on `chmod -R 777` on var/www/html &

```
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc var/cache var/generation -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;

find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc var/cache var/generation -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;


chmod u+x bin/magento
```

It is not working still,need suggestion to fix this

Comment: have you checked the file ownership

Comment: are you working on server or on local?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently theres a problem with a generated file somewhere
I went into 
`{magento-directory}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php`

around Line 194

i commented out :

```
 //$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
 //$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();
```

and replaced it with :

```
$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];
```

this just skips the Cron check altogether.

This is not the best solution . You can check devdocs  of magento too https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html